# Why do we have 3 types of X-selections in LINUX?

Tags: linux, arch-linux

`man xclip` says:

```
 -selection     specify which X selection to use, options are 
                "primary" to use XA_PRIMARY (default), "secondary" 
                for XA_SECONDARY or "clipboard" for XA_CLIPBOARD
```

Why do we have 3 types of X-Selections? What are their purposes?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Historical, partly.  I'm not sure "secondary" is used for anything at all anymore.

- "clipboard" is what is used by most <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>/<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>V</kbd>;
  it is the clipboard you put things into on purpose.
- "primary" is what holds whatever text is currently selected;
  it is how X keeps track of what is selected and conveniently may be pasted by middle clicking (or, if you're awesome, clicking right and left buttons at the same time) or by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> in `xterm`.

Comment: I'm not sure that secondary was *ever* really used...

Comment: Left and right clicking at the same time only works if your system is set up, so that left+right click simulates a middle-click, right?

Comment: Right.  It's just my preferred configuration :)

Answer (score 13):

Check [here](http://standards.freedesktop.org/clipboards-spec/clipboards-latest.txt) and [here](http://www.jwz.org/doc/x-cut-and-paste.html).

tl;dr: See Singpolyma's post.

Comment: Great links! Thanks to the 1st one I finally understand why my clipboard is empty when I copy text to it in vim and then close vim. And 2nd explained how it is possible that I can copy-paste formatted text.

Discussed implementation details and corner cases explained to me why X selection is so tricky.